# insert map into cassandra using cassandra-driver for node.js

Tags: node.js, dictionary, cassandra

I have a table named "user" in which I want to insert a map with a string key and integer value. I am using the cassandra-driver for node.js.

This is the code:

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var config = require('./config.js');
var cassandraClient = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: config.cassandra.hosts, keyspace: config.cassandra.keyspace});

var jsonObj = {"id":979,"cardId":17423,"categoryType":"C","user":"Çakal Karlos","email":"demo@email.com","phone":"+902124572020","companyId":4560,"companyCount":11,"userName":"userT6162pgc","password":"wq6162erwrr6162fd12","licenseList":[{"id":100,"code":"HD","count":1}]};
var map= {};
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.licenseList.length; i++){
    map[i] = {jsonObj.licenseList[i].code.concat(':').concat(jsonObj.licenseList[i].id).toString) : jsonObj.licenseList[i].count];
}
console.log(map[0]);
var params = [jsonObj.userName,jsonObj.cardId, jsonObj.categoryType, jsonObj.companyCount, jsonObj.companyId, jsonObj.email, jsonObj.id, map[0], jsonObj.password, jsonObj.phone, jsonObj.user];

cassandraClient.execute(config.query, params, {prepare: true}, function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Row updated on the cluster');
});
```

When I query the table, the result is,

```
 username     | cardid | categorytype | companycount | companyid | email          | id  | licenselist | password            | phone         | user
--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------
 userT6162pgc |  17423 |            C |           11 |      4560 | demo@email.com | 979 |        null | wq6162erwrr6162fd12 | +902124572020 | \xc7akal Karlos
```

I cannot insert the map, I cannot create the map. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var config = require('./config.js');
var cassandraClient = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: config.cassandra.hosts, keyspace: config.cassandra.keyspace});

var jsonObj = {"id":979,"cardId":17423,"categoryType":"C","user":"Çakal Karlos","email":"demo@email.com","phone":"+902124572020","companyId":4560,"companyCount":11,"userName":"userT6162pgc","password":"wq6162erwrr6162fd12","licenseList":[{"id":100,"code":"HD","count":1}]};

var map= {};
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.licenseList.length; i++){
    map[jsonObj.licenseList[i].code+':'+jsonObj.licenseList[i].id] = jsonObj.licenseList[i].count;
}
console.log(map);
var params = [jsonObj.userName,jsonObj.cardId, jsonObj.categoryType, jsonObj.companyCount, jsonObj.companyId, jsonObj.email, jsonObj.id, map, jsonObj.password, jsonObj.phone, jsonObj.user];

cassandraClient.execute(config.query, params, {prepare: true}, function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Row updated on the cluster');
});
```